# Count and group by join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table for products and a table for users who have bought products. On the products table A there is site_name which determines where the products were bought.

Table B shows the users and what they have bought.

I am using the following to show a list of products bought, by site_name, grouping the product name together.

```
SELECT product FROM A JOIN B ON A.prod_id = B.prod_id WHERE A.site_name = 'ebay' group by A.product
```

Table A for products is:

```
prod_id
site_name
product
```

Table B for users is:

```
user_id
prod_id
```

What i can't figure out is how to get the number of products bought per line.

e.g. in table A there is

```
prod_id    site_name    product
-------    ---------    -------
1          ebay         chair
2          amazon       desk
3          ebay         lamp
```

and on table b

```
user_id    prod_id
-------    -------
1000         1
1001         2
1002         1
1003         3
```

So I want to show each line where site_name is ebay and how many products were bought, order by most first like:

```
chair    2
lamp     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minor change to Michael's query.

```
SELECT
    products.product,
    COUNT(users.prod_id) AS productsBought
FROM
    A AS products
    INNER JOIN B AS users
        ON products.prod_id = users.prod_id
WHERE products.site_name = 'ebay'
GROUP BY products.product
```

The above query will not return products that haven't been bought.

Comment: Many thanks for your help! Both work perfectly but this does seem a little faster.

Answer (score 4):

I would use a `LEFT JOIN`, so that if there is a product that has never been purchased, it will show up with a count of 0.

Also, I would use `COUNT(users.prod_id)`, instead of `COUNT(*)`, so that it will only count rows which have satisfied the `LEFT JOIN` condition:

```
SELECT
    products.product,
    COUNT(users.prod_id) AS productsBought
FROM
    A AS products
    LEFT JOIN B AS users
        ON products.prod_id = users.prod_id
WHERE products.site_name = 'ebay'
GROUP BY products.product
```

Comment: Thank you so much, quick question... there will never be a product that has never been bought... imagine meeting 1000 people and asking what have you bought and they start with a list, there will always be one that has bought one, or the product would not appear, but hence there may be more users who have bought the same product  - does that make sense? does that alter anything?

Comment: Assuming that every user has bought atleast one product then you can change the Query to use an Inner Join rather than a Left Join, since Left join returns all rows from the product table even if it hasnt been purchased (slow when compared to an Inner join).

Comment: you have an example @Prakash?

Comment: @DarrenSweeney To switch from a `left join` to an `inner join`, you can simply remove the word `left` in the query above.  However, I wouldn't make assumptions about products having been purchased at least once.  What if a new product is just added, and no one has had a chance to buy it yet?  What if there is a glitch in the system that prevents a specific product from being purchased?  What if the product is something like `Pluto Nash Blu-Ray Deluxe Edition`, which no one will ever buy?

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson I own that! Just kidding. The products table is built on someone adding it... it not a shopping site more a "i have bought have you?" site